# Intel XDK | Android App | Can't post user input to facebook group

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, post, intel-xdk

I want to post user input to a facebook group feed. the login works fine with permission "user_groups".

If I try to post a fix string to the group feed it works fine, but when I use the string of an input field the function to post doesn't do anything.

when I call an alert in the function with the input field string value as message it works.

Here the HTML site:

```
    <div class="input_element form_element" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin-top: 10px;" data-appbuilder-object="input">
    <label for="txt_meldung">Meldung</label>
    <input type="text" style="float:left;" value="Blitzer" id="txt_meldung" placeholder="">                      
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#" style="" data-appbuilder-object="button" data-transition="slide"
        id="btn_melden" onclick="fbpost()">Blitzer melden</a>
    </div>
```

and here the JS Site:

```
function fblogin() {
// alert("Hier kommt das Login Fenster"); 
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.login",function(e){ 
if (e.success === true) 
{ 
 console.log("Facebook Log in Successful"); 
   alert(e.name);
   alert(e.access_token);
} 
else
{ 
   console.log("Unsuccessful Login"); 
} 
},false); 
intel.xdk.facebook.login("publish_stream,publish_actions,user_groups,offline_access");
}

function fbpost() {
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.facebook.requestWithGraphAPI",function(e){ 
if (e.success === true) 
{ 
  console.log("Facebook Post Successful"); 
    alert("Blitzer gemeldet");
} 
else
{ 
  console.log("Unsuccessful Post"); 
    alert("Error: " + e.message);
} 
},false); 
   var facebookGroupID = "207596109276686"; // group-id
   var Meldung = document.getElementById("txt_meldung").value; // user input text
   //alert(Meldung); <-- this works!!!
   intel.xdk.facebook.requestWithGraphAPI(facebookGroupID + "/feed?message=" + Meldung + "&access_token=CAAGaaXRj8wEBABhVef9lzvQHgj3OZB3pe4Spo0hmuXT1ANC5KY9lTQ1pHddwS082iC7nyHZBjM75Nj0apxeF6NWwIgZA0ReVDlHN4ZATgrzI6BKM96aXxR4WkvWyOgnjcVZAfhIqXC2hQnmQwlrH7auLGi84LKxWNwABJcEyUS8W61A7tHZA3DdTQWev9QM7xt5yIxSemBdQg9pZAL3t1Kz0c2CZCW64GekZD","POST","");
}
```

This works. Access_Token same as above

```
intel.xdk.facebook.requestWithGraphAPI(facebookGroupID + "/feed?message=TESTMESSAGE&access_token=myaccesstoken","POST","");
```

Thanks @ all who will help ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when the user input contains spaces. Without spaces the posting works. Any idea what I have to fix in my code?

Must be the JS site where I have to fix it.

Comment: Single upper quotes don't fix it